# Nonlinear ODE and $_2\text{F}_1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, hypergeometric-function

Consider the differential equation $y'(x) = B \, y(x)^{-b} - A \, y(x)^a$ to which [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29%20%3D%20B%2Fy%5Eb%20-%20A%20y%5Ea) returns the following:

$$x - c_1 = \frac{y(x)^{b+1}}{B\,(b+1)} \; _2\text{F}_1 \left( 1, \frac{b+1}{a+b}; 1 + \frac{b+1}{a+b}; \frac{A}{B} \, y(x)^{a+b} \right)$$

Is there a way to turn this into an explicit expression for $y(x)$ or to approximate the solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let $Y = A y^{a + b}/B$, then the ODE becomes $Y' = k (1 - Y) Y^{1 - p}$ with $p > 0$, $k > 0$. The solution with $Y(0) = Y_0$ is
$$F(Y) - F(Y_0) = k x, \\
F(Y) = \frac {Y^p} p \hspace {1.5 px} {_2 F_1}(1, p; p + 1; Y).$$
Any solution with $Y_0 > 0$ converges to the equilibrium point $Y = 1$, where $F$ has a logarithmic singularity. The limiting behavior for $x \to \infty$ is given by
$$-\ln(1 - Y) - H_{p - 1} - F(Y_0) + o(1) = k x, \\
Y = 1 - (1 + o(1)) e^{-k x - H_{p - 1} - F(Y_0)}.$$
If $Y_0 > 1$, we choose consistent analytic continuations of $\ln$ and $F$ (or take $Y = 1/Y$).

Comment: @Maxim what is $H_{p-1}$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = B \, y(x)^{-b} - A \, y(x)^a$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$x=\int\frac {dy}{B\,y^{-b} - A \, y^a} $$
$$x=\frac{1}{B(b+1)}y^{b+1}\;_2F_1\left(1\:,\:\frac{b+1}{a+b}\:;\:\frac{a+2b+1}{a+b}\:;\:\frac{A}{B}y^{a+b}\right)+\text{constant}$$
$y(x)$ is the inverse function of the above.

There is no available closed form for the inverse function $y(x)$.

Simplification might occur for particular values of the parameters $a,b,A,B\:$  but not in the general case.

Approximate formulas could be derived but arduous and valid only on limited ranges depending on $a,b,A,B$ . One could use the series expension of the hypergeometric function and the method of reversion of series : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html . Since this involves complicated numerical calculus it should be much simpler to directly solve the original ODE thanks to numerical calculus.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $x,y,a,b,A,B \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Does that help with the derivation?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the question should have your ideas on how to solve the problem.

The answer is yes, but it needs a limit since your hypergeometric function is a [Lerch Transcendent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Lerch+Transcendent). Here is the “closed form” solution using the Wolfram Language’s [Incomplete Beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Beta%28z%2Ca%2Cb%29) and [**Inverse Beta Regularized $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Inverse+beta+regularized):

$$x - c= \frac{y^{b+1}}{B\,(b+1)} \; _2\text{F}_1 \left( 1, \frac{b+1}{a+b}; 1 + \frac{b+1}{a+b}; \frac{A}{B} \, y^{a+b} \right)=  \frac{y^{b+1}}{B\,(b+1)} \frac{b+1}{a+b}\left( \frac{A}{B} \, y^{a+b} \right)^{-\frac{b+1}{a+b}}\text B_{ \frac{A}{B} \, y^{a+b} }\left(\frac{b+1}{a+b},0\right)\mathop=^{a,b\in\Bbb R^+}   \frac{\text B_{ \frac{A}{B} \, y^{a+b} }\left(\frac{b+1}{a+b},0\right)}{\sqrt[a+b]{A^{b+1}B^{a-1}}(a+b)}$$

Now invert:

$$\boxed{y’=By^{-b}-Ay^a\implies y=\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt[a+b]{\frac BA\text I^{-1}_{\left(\frac AB\right)^\frac{b+1}{a+b}(a+b)Bt(x-c)}\left(\frac{b+1}{a+b},t\right)}}$$

[**which**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28B+InverseBetaRegularized%5BB+%28A%2FB%29%5E%28%28b%2B1%29%2F%28a+%2B+b%29%29+%28a+%2B+b%29+10%5E-9+x%2C+%281+%2B+b%29%2F%28a+%2B+b%29%2C+10%5E-9%5D%29%2FA%29%5E%28a+%2B+b%29%5E%28-1%29%2Ca%3De%2Cb%3Dcatalan%2CA%3Dpi%2CB%3Dkhinchin%2Cx%3Deulergamma) [**works**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulergamma-y%5E%28b%2B1%29%2F%28%28b%2B1%29B%29+2F1%281%2C%28b%2B1%29%2F%28a%2Bb%29%2C%28b%2B1%29%2F%28a%2Bb%29%2B1%2CA%2FB+y%5E%28a%2Bb%29%29%2Ca%3De%2Cb%3Dcatalan%2CA%3Dpi%2CB%3Dkhinchin%2Cy%3D0.95571261923631) when you use the decimal answer from the left bolded link and compare use it like in the right bolded link.

Take $t\to0$ to adjust the accuracy